# How does one make a Phabricator instance public?

Tags: phabricator

I've played around with the Config settings a bit and searched the docs, but haven't been able to find any information on this.

Phacility's own Phabricator instance works this way a(nd I've seen other installations as well), so I assume that there must be a relatively simple way of setting this up, but haven't found it.

Specifically:

- How to get a Phabricator instance to switch to the default Dashboard, rather than the login view for anonymous users accessing the site?
- How to set visibility on tasks to default to "Public", rather than "All Users"?

---

Edit: Solved the issue with the dashboard not showing up - apparently, the settings of any individual panel in the dashboard overrule the dashboard settings.

To clarify: If one panel in the dashboard is set up to a higher restriction (e.g., "All Users" instead of "Public") than the dashboard itself is, then the Panel's restrictions override the restrictions set on the dashboard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## How to show the default Dashboard, rather than the login view, for anonymous users

1. Go to **"Config"**
2. Go to **"Policy"**
3. Go to **"policy.allow-public"**
4. Set the Value to **"Allow Public Visibility"**
5. Click **"Save Config Entry"**

NOTE: Once you have set the Public Dashboard, you will need to verify that all panels in that dashboard have public visibility.

## How to set default visibility on tasks to "Public", rather than "All Users"

1. Navigate to **"Applications"**
2. Click the gear icon next to **"Maniphest"** (In newer versions the gear icon has been replaced with a **"Configure"** button.)
3. Click **"Edit Policies"**
4. Set the desired policy defaults
5. Click **Save Policies**

Comment: Unfortunately, this setting was already correctly set. But it did make me think of one thing, which was whether all of the panels in the public dashboard were set up correctly. Turns out that there was one panel in the dashboard that had not been corrected - set to All Users instead of Public, and that was enough to overrule the setting for the dashboard itself.

Comment: Added information received from an "anonymous user" that should help.

Comment: Many thanks. Not the most intuitive place to go digging for this, but there it was. :D

Comment: @michael-a Could you edit the answer to include your comment or publish it as a new answer?

Comment: it is not updated, i cannot see the "Edit Policies" under Maniphest

Comment: @DavidH Are you sure you are clicking on the gear icon (or the "Configure" link in newer versions)?  When you do, it will take you to a page that provides a brief description and lists the different policies.  The "Edit Policies" link is on the far right along with an "Uninstall"

Comment: finally found that menu(little icon).