# Anonymous http in phabricator

Tags: phabricator

How to configure *phabricator* to support anonymous http?

I follow the [official guide](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_hosting/), it seems use http for repositories hosting required

`diffusion.allow-http-auth` is **enabled**,

But I want to enable anonymous http, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you're asking I'm assuming public access versus user access.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136586/how-does-one-make-a-phabricator-instance-public)

Otherwise I don't think it's possible for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It is more than a year since the question was posted, but here is the answer if someone bumps into this:

1. For HTTP repository access you need to enable `diffusion.allow-http-auth` as you did.
2. For general anonymous access to Phabricator you need to enable `policy.allow-public`, as mentioned in the Answer @Jorden linked to.
3. Now for specific repository public access (Anonymous), you need to set the **Visible** policy for the repository to **Public (No login required)**.

Hope this helps